# Inquiry about returned data of DHT11

Tags: arduino, temperature, measurement

I'm using DHT22 for my measurement of temperature and humidity. As mentioned in its datasheet, data that returns from DHT22 is formatted in 40bit which consists of 8 bit integral RH, 8-bit decimal data, and the others for Temperature and checksum. However, its resolution is actually up to 1℃ or 1%RH, which means the decimal part should be zero for measured results. So, why it exists? Did I misunderstand something? Hope for your clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/DHT22.pdf) says the resolution is 0.1% RH and 0.1°C. So the decimal part is needed to send that data.